# How to implemented for geographic spatial reference systems in mysql

Tags: mysql, geometry, buffer, gis, geojson

I want to create a buffer from 10m within a point with latitude and longitude. So I tried

```
SET @json = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [139.445699080589, 35.507941895691]}');
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Buffer(@json,10));
```

But I got error:

```
[22001][3618] Data truncation: st_buffer(POINT, ...) has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems.
```

How to implemente geographic spatial in this situation ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something you as user can implement. This error tells you MySQL itself did not implement ST_Buffer function for the case of geographic SRS.

The issue is there are two types of SRS - projected (planar map, also called Cartesian), and geographic (on ellipsoid). In other systems they are usually represented by separate types, geometry (planar) and geography (ellipsoid). In MySQL it is one type with either projected or ellipsoid SRS.

Some algorithms on ellipsoid are more complex, so some functionality in MySQL spatial is not implemented for that case yet.

Your options are

1) switch to appropriate projected SRS if possible,

2) switch to another platform, e.g. PostgreSQL + PostGIS that supports ST_Buffer for Geography type,

3) avoid ST_Buffer (it is often misused to check buffered intersection when ST_DWithin should be used, although I don't know your specific use case)